# Setting up svn repository

Tags: svn, ssh

I recently setup svn on a Windows 2003 server over ssh. I'm familiar with the developer end of svn, but I've never had to be the admin. The point of it is to allow remote development through visual studio. I have an existing directory with all files for my site that was not previously under version control. The site points to this directory, and so I do not want to move these files.

How do I create a repository and add all the existing files to it without having to move them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: create repository and its necessary branches/tags/trunk structure on server and make it available over network via apache or svnserve:

```
svnadmin create /opt/svn/myrepo
svn mkdir file:///opt/svn/myrepo/trunk -m "creating repo structure"
svnserve -d -r /opt/svn/
```

2nd: check out repositories target folder(eg trunk) into your topmost directory of your source code:

```
svn co http://[YOUR_SERVER]/myrepo/trunk c:\development\myproject\src
```

3rd: commit source code into repository as initial import

```
svn commit -m "initial import of myproject"
```

You can also use the **svn import** command, however this one will allow you to continue your development without another check out of your source code.

Also note that I did not create the full repository structure because of brevity, usually you would do this by creating the top level folder and using **svn import**

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated: `svnadmin create /path/to/repository` will create the repository for you. You'll then have to have some server mechanism. I'm not sure how you'll do *svn+ssh* on Windows since `sshd` is not part of the standard Windows utility. You can use `svnserve` directly or download [CollabNet Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/) which will integrate Apache with Subversion (and ViewVC) in one package.

What I recommend though, is that you read the on line book about [Subversion Administration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin). This is a fairly quick read, well written, and will get you up and running on the Subversion server end in no time.

Comment: Yes I had a lot of trouble with svn+ssh. I switched over to port 443. Got it working great.